# Unable to use object type as method argument in scala shell

Tags: scala, scala-repl

The following code doesn't' work in scala shell, but it works in IDE, does anyone how can I use object type as method parameter in scala-shell, thanks.

```
scala> object A {
     | }
defined object A

scala> def f(a:A) :Unit = {
     | }
<console>:63: error: not found: type A
       def f(a:A) :Unit = {
```

Comment: Just a thought, a function that accepts a unique singleton as its sole argument, is it not just a [`thunk`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object.type like this:

```
scala> object A {}
defined object A

scala> def f(a: A.type) = println("hello world")
f: (a: A.type)Unit

scala> f(A)
hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add trait A :

```
trait A
object A extends A
def f(a:A) :Unit = { }
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by *works in IDE*? I created a project with one file, `HelloWorld1`, where its content is:

```
object HelloWorld1 extends App {
  
  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    object A {

    }

    def f(a:A) :Unit = {}
  }
}
```

When compiling I am getting the following error:

```
HelloWorld1.scala:8:13
not found: type A
    def f(a:A) :Unit = {}
```

As mentioned in the two answers above, you can either do:

```
def f(a:A.type) :Unit = {}
```

Or define trait instead of object:

```
trait A
```